# Add lines to Google Bubble Chart

Tags: charts, google-visualization, bubble-chart

I am learning to use Google Charts and I'm trying to add vertical and horizontal lines into my bubble chart (see the chart on [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fckz2qyu/)).

```
  <div id="series_bubble_div" style="width: 1300px; height: 600px;"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
         google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawSeriesChart);

    function drawSeriesChart() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['May', 'Profit', 'Loss', 'Color', 'Amount'],
          ['One', -0.0200677317826359, 0.00783908666680255, "Blue", 2.90062193473149],
          ['Two', -0.000769939209045673, -0.000869129717442352, "Red", 0.393370989830078],
          ['Three', 0.231046771318721, -0.023, "Blue", 4.22746171],
          ['Four', -0.11516787308815, 0.0307, "Red", 1.58054636957],
          ['Five', -0.156171745810591, 0.002, "Blue", 4.478502636],
          ['Six', -0.0539915684061078, 0.0117, "Red", 1.396314864],
          ['Seven', -0.00718037723705341, -0.011, "Blue", 1.31638390999998],
          ['Eight', -0.0562574430733049, 0.0411, "Red", 8.39198070530399],
          ['Nine', 0.235522678055354, -0.005, "Blue", 8.70835673000001],
          ['Ten', 0.226171773714415, -0.0164, "Red", 5.66191157875001],
          ['Eleven', -0.0805926930562123, -0.00600000000000001, "Blue", 4.74257550999999],
          ['Twelve', 0.0642371105755089, 0.0675, "Red", 0.630424760336]
        ]);

        var options = {
            title: 'My graph, May 2017',
            hAxis: {title: 'Profit',format: 'percent', minValue: -0.05, maxValue: 0.10 },
            vAxis: {title: 'Loss',format: 'percent', minValue: -0.03, maxValue: 0.06 },
            bubble: { textStyle: { fontSize: 11 } },
            axisTitlesPosition: 'out'

        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.BubbleChart(document.getElementById('series_bubble_div'));

               chart.draw(data, options);
               }
    </script>
```

In the picture below is the effect, that I want to achieve. Horizontal lines should be at +1.5% and -1.5%, vertical lines at +7% and -7%. The area between the lines should have another color than the rest of the chart area.

Do you have any idea, how to reach it?

[image: Desired result of bubble chart with lines]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can add lines / color segments into the bubble chart itself, but you could fake an effect like this by overlaying the bubble chart with line charts (you'd need two - one for the vertical lines and one for the horizontal lines), and an area chart to fill the middle. Once the charts have been created you would then have to line them up, so that they fall in the proper spot.

```js
  google.charts.load('current', {
      'packages': ['corechart']
  });
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawSeriesChart);

  function drawSeriesChart() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['May', 'Profit', 'Loss', 'Color', 'Amount'],
          ['One', -0.0200677317826359, 0.00783908666680255, "Blue", 2.90062193473149],
          ['Two', -0.000769939209045673, -0.000869129717442352, "Red", 0.393370989830078],
          ['Three', 0.231046771318721, -0.023, "Blue", 4.22746171],
          ['Four', -0.11516787308815, 0.0307, "Red", 1.58054636957],
          ['Five', -0.156171745810591, 0.002, "Blue", 4.478502636],
          ['Six', -0.0539915684061078, 0.0117, "Red", 1.396314864],
          ['Seven', -0.00718037723705341, -0.011, "Blue", 1.31638390999998],
          ['Eight', -0.0562574430733049, 0.0411, "Red", 8.39198070530399],
          ['Nine', 0.235522678055354, -0.005, "Blue", 8.70835673000001],
          ['Ten', 0.226171773714415, -0.0164, "Red", 5.66191157875001],
          ['Eleven', -0.0805926930562123, -0.00600000000000001, "Blue", 4.74257550999999],
          ['Twelve', 0.0642371105755089, 0.0675, "Red", 0.630424760336]
      ]);

      var options = {
          title: 'My graph, May 2017',
          hAxis: {
              title: 'Profit',
              format: 'percent',
              minValue: -0.05,
              maxValue: 0.10
          },
          vAxis: {
              title: 'Loss',
              format: 'percent',
              minValue: -0.03,
              maxValue: 0.06
          },
          bubble: {
              textStyle: {
                  fontSize: 11
              }
          },
          axisTitlesPosition: 'out'

      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.BubbleChart(document.getElementById('series_bubble_div'));

      chart.draw(data, options);

      var chartH = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
          chartType: 'LineChart',
          containerId: 'line_h_div',
          dataTable: [
              ['x', '1', '2'],
              [0, 20, 40],
              [100, 20, 40]
          ],
          options: {
              hAxis: {
                  minValue: 0,
                  maxValue: 100,
                  textPosition: 'none',
                  gridlines: {
                      color: 'none'
                  },
                  baselineColor: 'none'
              },
              vAxis: {
                  minValue: 0,
                  maxValue: 100,
                  textPosition: 'none',
                  gridlines: {
                      color: 'none'
                  },
                  baselineColor: 'none'
              },
              colors: ['green'],
              pointSize: 0,
              lineWidth: 2,
              enableInteractivity: false,
              legend: {
                  position: 'none'
              },
              backgroundColor: 'transparent'
          }
      });
      chartH.draw();

      var chartV = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
          chartType: 'LineChart',
          containerId: 'line_v_div',
          dataTable: [
              ['x', '1', '2'],
              [0, 20, 40],
              [100, 20, 40]
          ],
          options: {
              hAxis: {
                  minValue: 0,
                  maxValue: 100,
                  textPosition: 'none',
                  gridlines: {
                      color: 'none'
                  },
                  baselineColor: 'none'
              },
              vAxis: {
                  minValue: 0,
                  maxValue: 100,
                  textPosition: 'none',
                  gridlines: {
                      color: 'none'
                  },
                  baselineColor: 'none'
              },
              colors: ['green'],
              pointSize: 0,
              lineWidth: 2,
              enableInteractivity: false,
              legend: {
                  position: 'none'
              },
              backgroundColor: 'transparent',
              orientation: 'vertical'
          }
      });
      chartV.draw();

      var chartArea = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
          chartType: 'AreaChart',
          containerId: 'area_div',
          dataTable: [
              ['x', '1', '2'],
              [0, 20, 0],
              [20, 20, 0],
              [20, 20, 20],
              [40, 20, 20],
              [40, 20, 0],
              [100, 20, 0]
          ],
          options: {
              hAxis: {
                  minValue: 0,
                  maxValue: 100,
                  textPosition: 'none',
                  gridlines: {
                      color: 'none'
                  },
                  baselineColor: 'none'
              },
              vAxis: {
                  minValue: 0,
                  maxValue: 100,
                  textPosition: 'none',
                  gridlines: {
                      color: 'none'
                  },
                  baselineColor: 'none'
              },
              colors: ['none', 'green'],
              pointSize: 0,
              lineWidth: 1,
              enableInteractivity: false,
              legend: {
                  position: 'none'
              },
              backgroundColor: 'transparent',
              isStacked: true
          }
      });
      chartArea.draw();
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="series_bubble_div" style="width: 1300px; height: 600px;"></div>
<div id="line_v_div" style="width: 1300px; height: 600px; position: absolute; top:8px"></div>
<div id="line_h_div" style="width: 1300px; height: 600px; position: absolute; top:0"></div>
<div id="area_div" style="width: 1300px; height: 600px; position: absolute; top:0"></div>
```

**edit**

As suggested by @dlaliberte - you can actually convert the whole thing to a scatter plot and display the desired result without having to overlay plots.

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
    'packages': ['corechart']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawSeriesChart);

function drawSeriesChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('number', 'Profit');
    data.addColumn('number', 'line');
    data.addColumn('number', 'area');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Loss');
    data.addColumn({
        type: 'string',
        role: 'style'
    });
    data.addColumn({
        type: 'string',
        role: 'annotation'
    });
    data.addRows([
        [-0.0200677317826359, null, null, 0.00783908666680255, "color: blue; stroke-width: " + 2.90062193473149 * 10, 'One'],
        [-0.000769939209045673, null, null, -0.000869129717442352, "color: red; stroke-width: " + 0.393370989830078 * 10, 'Two'],
        [0.231046771318721, null, null, -0.023, "color: blue; stroke-width: " + 4.22746171 * 10, 'Three'],
        [-0.11516787308815, null, null, 0.0307, "color: red; stroke-width: " + 1.58054636957 * 10, 'Four'],
        [-0.156171745810591, null, null, 0.002, "color: blue; stroke-width: " + 4.478502636 * 10, 'Five'],
        [-0.0539915684061078, null, null, 0.0117, "color: red; stroke-width: " + 1.396314864 * 10, 'Six'],
        [-0.00718037723705341, null, null, -0.011, "color: blue; stroke-width: " + 1.31638390999998 * 10, 'Seven'],
        [-0.0562574430733049, null, null, 0.0411, "color: red; stroke-width: " + 8.39198070530399 * 10, 'Eight'],
        [0.235522678055354, null, null, -0.005, "color: blue; stroke-width: " + 8.70835673000001 * 10, 'Nine'],
        [0.226171773714415, null, null, -0.0164, "color: red; stroke-width: " + 5.66191157875001 * 10, 'Ten'],
        [-0.0805926930562123, null, null, -0.00600000000000001, "color: blue; stroke-width: " + 4.74257550999999 * 10, 'Eleven'],
        [0.0642371105755089, null, null, 0.0675, "color: red; stroke-width: " + 0.630424760336 * 10, 'Twelve'],
        [-0.3, 0.015, null, null, null, null],
        [0.3, 0.015, null, null, null, null],
        [null, null, null, null, null, null],
        [-0.3, -0.015, null, null, null, null],
        [0.3, -0.015, null, null, null, null],
        [null, null, null, null, null, null],
        [-0.07, 0.09, null, null, null, null],
        [-0.07, -0.03, null, null, null, null],
        [null, null, null, null, null, null],
        [0.07, 0.09, null, null, null, null],
        [0.07, -0.03, null, null, null, null],
        [null, null, null, null, null, null],
        [-0.07, null, 0.015, null, null, null],
        [0.07, null, 0.015, null, null, null],
        [null, null, null, null, null, null],
        [-0.07, null, -0.015, null, null, null],
        [0.07, null, -0.015, null, null, null],
    ]);

    var options = {
        title: 'My graph, May 2017',
        hAxis: {
            title: 'Profit',
            format: 'percent',
            viewWindowMode: 'explicit',
            viewWindow: {
                max: -0.3,
                min: 0.3
            }
        },
        vAxis: {
            title: 'Loss',
            format: 'percent',
            viewWindowMode: 'explicit',
            viewWindow: {
                max: 0.09,
                min: -0.03
            }
        },
        bubble: {
            textStyle: {
                fontSize: 11
            }
        },
        series: {
            0: {
                lineWidth: 2,
                pointSize: 0,
                color: 'green'
            },
            1: {
                type: 'area',
                pointSize: 0,
                color: 'green'
            }
        },
        axisTitlesPosition: 'out',
        legend: 'none'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('series_bubble_div'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="series_bubble_div" style="width: 1300px; height: 600px;"></div>
```

Comment: You could do a little less faking and overlaying if you convert the bubble chart into a scatter chart with styles and annotations, and then add a series for drawing the lines (with nulls between to break the line into separate segments).  The green area might be the hardest to fake, though it turns out you can draw polygons with the 'area' series just by closing the line segments around a region.

Comment: @dlaliberte can you set individual point sizes in a scatter chart without making a series for each point?

Comment: Yes, you can use a 'style' role to set the point size and color of each scatter point.

Comment: @dlaliberte ok, thank you. I'll try to add a demo for this a bit later today